# How Disbale Uninstall Options for Application Using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to Build a Application Using Flutter( For Android ) When I was Installing the Application It would became the default Mobile Application and It Can't be able to Uninstall that App from that device.

I was tried with InvokeMethod channel but it won't work that Code

In Flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const platform = MethodChannel('your_channel_name');
Future<void> setUninstallBlocked(String packageName, bool uninstallBlocked) async {
  try {
    await platform.invokeMethod('setUninstallBlocked', {
      'packageName': packageName,
      'uninstallBlocked': uninstallBlocked,
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the invocation
    print('Error: ${e.message}');
  }
}
```

Kotlin Code

```
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "your_channel_name"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "setUninstallBlocked" -> {
                    val packageName = call.argument<String>("packageName")
                    val uninstallBlocked = call.argument<Boolean>("uninstallBlocked")

                    setUninstallBlocked(packageName, uninstallBlocked, result)
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUninstallBlocked(packageName: String?, uninstallBlocked: Boolean?, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        if (packageName != null && uninstallBlocked != null) {
            val adminComponent = ComponentName(this, YourDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)
            val devicePolicyManager = getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager

            devicePolicyManager.setUninstallBlocked(adminComponent, packageName, uninstallBlocked)
            
            result.success(null)
        } else {
            result.error("INVALID_ARGUMENTS", "Invalid arguments", null)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent uninstall is by Device Ownership (a deprecated system you can't use in a downloadable app anyway) or via Android Enterprise (which requires the device to be registered as owned by your organization, so basically it works for devices you own only).  A normal user app cannot do this, because its basically malware if it could.

There is no such thing as a "default mobile application".  If you mean you're building a kiosk, what you want to do is build a launcher app, and use Android Enterprise to lock down the device.

Comment: I don't that app in play store If I install via the apk file if it is possible to add that function

Comment: No, you'd still need to use Android Enterprise to do it.  But if you're talking about a device you own and will be installing via APK, that probably does become an option.  https://support.google.com/work/android/topic/9621435  look at the full device management section